# Unit test stage failed when running on public server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests using the Jest package, and I've set up my test environment as follows:

```js
let mongo;

beforeAll(async () => {
  try {
    mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    const uri = mongo.getUri();

    mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
    await mongoose.connect(uri, {
      socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
      keepAlive: true,
      autoIndex: true,
      retryWrites: false,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new DatabaseConnectionError();
  }
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const collection of collections) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
  logger.info('Collections deleted successfully!');
});

afterAll(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.disconnect();
    await mongo.stop();
    logger.info('MongoDB connection closed successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
    setTimeout(disconnectMongoDB, 3000);
  }
});
```

When I run my unit tests locally, everything works fine. However, when I try to run them on the server, I encounter the following error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collections')

> 37 |   const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();
     |                                                    ^
  38 |   // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  39 |   for (const collection of collections) {
  40 |     // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
```

Can someone who has encountered this issue or has information on how to resolve it please help?